# How do I run a funsuite test within a for loop?

Tags: scala, testing

I am very new to scala so trying to understand how funsuite testing works. I have a bunch of tests that take a method data() to set it as a particular method from a variety of methods namely method1(): Long, method2(): Long etc

I figured defining the method1/2/... etc within the class would be fine and then sequentially go through them for my tests rather than having to write duplicate tests for each method, but seems like the data cannot be found by the tests. I also tried putting both the tests inside the for loop but then I am having issues with the IDE not being able to find tests. What am I doing wrong?

Example

```
class controlTest extends Anyfunsuite {
   protected def method1(): Long = { a() }
   protected def method2(): Long = { b() }
   protected def method3(): Long = { c() }

  for(i <- Seq(method1(), method2(), method3()) {
     def data(): Long = i
  }

  test("testing1"){
    data()
    ....
  }

 test("testing2"){
   data()
   ...
 }
```

Comment: With `AnyFunSuite`, Scala treats each `test` as a function value, and calls each sequentially.  Now I don't know what `a(), b(), c()` are in your code, but this does not compile. Why not run `method1()` in `testing1`, `method2()` in `testing2`, etc. ?

Comment: @AlinGabrielArhip `a(), b(), c()` are methods that take longs and return longs. For my scenario for each test I want `method1(), method2() and so on to run`

Comment: No, as are written, `a(), b(), c()` don't take any `Long`, just result in one. Can you be more specific of what you want to achieve? It's unclear. "for each test I want method1(), method2() and so on to run" -  You want to call all methods in each test ? Or just one method in each test ?

Comment: @AlinGabrielArhip I want to call all methods for each test. Each method has a unique ID that gets returned and I need to run my test to make sure each unique ID is correctly making the API call. Each Unique ID returned is associated with an enrollment number and they're equal to the number of methods. So If I had to write each test say 3 times for `method1(), method2(), method3()` the testing class becomes too long if I have 100 tests that need to be tested for all 3 of these methods.

Comment: What about using this: https://www.scalatest.org/scaladoc/3.2.13/org/scalatest/propspec/AnyPropSpec.html